# Trying to post a tweet in java with Twitter4J

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to write a simple application that posts a tweet every time I run the program.
I've been trying to figure out how to get the credentials, but I just can't figure it out. This is what I have so far:

```
public void tweet() {
        try {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey("consumer key here");
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret("consumer secret here");
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();

        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();

            twitter.updateStatus("test");
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

To be clear, this isn't for a website or anything, it's just for when I run this program in eclipse, it should tweet for me.

If I'm not clear enough, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register an app at twitter: https://apps.twitter.com/ to get your token info. Read documentation for more info.